# Stream Writer not writing to file, no exception have file.close();

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following code: http://pastebin.com/HSjspbek

```
if (direction == "left" && mazearray[xIndex - 1, yIndex].canPass == false && x <= (xIndex * 18) + 3)
{

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\vroy\Desktop\LOG.txt");

    file.WriteLine("ENTERING LEFT");
    file.WriteLine(x + " , " + y);
    if (PacMan.yIndex > yIndex)
    {
        file.WriteLine("yIndex more");
    }
    if (PacMan.yIndex < yIndex)
    {
        file.WriteLine("yIndex less");
    }
    if (PacMan.xIndex == xIndex)
    {
        file.WriteLine("xIndex same");
    }
    file.WriteLine("METHOD CALL ENDED");


    if (PacMan.yIndex > yIndex && mazearray[xIndex, yIndex + 1].canPass == true)
    {
        direction = "down";
        Console.WriteLine("CHOICE DOWN");
        return;
    }
    if (PacMan.yIndex < yIndex && mazearray[xIndex, yIndex].canPass == true && y <= (yIndex * 18) + 3)
    {
        file.WriteLine("ENTERING UP");
        direction = "up";
        return;
    }
    if (PacMan.xIndex == xIndex)
    {
        if (mazearray[xIndex, yIndex + 1].canPass == true)
        {
            direction = "down";

        }
        else
        {
            direction = "up";
        }


    }
    file.Close();
}
```

As you can see there is a close method for the streamwriter object near the end of the method. Yet the text file I am writing too does not change.

Comment: Next time, you can write your code in your question as a text instead of just linking to pastebin page.

Comment: May no directly answer your question but instead of writing your own logs, use something like log4net. Will make your life much easier.

Comment: @silent: *If* the context allows for that. I once searched for a logging library that did not restrict my future choices of platforms, and back then, I ended up giving up, because all common logging libraries seemed to have some restrictions concerning use in Silverlight, in Mono, in Mono for Android, etc.

Comment: Ok, granted. But even if you decide to do it yourself, at least you should encapsulate the logging into a seperate function etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `StreamWriter` in a using statement:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\vroy\Desktop\LOG.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine("ENTERING LEFT");

    // Rest of code...
}
```

This essentially puts the code in a `try / finally` block with the `Close / Dispose` inside the `finally`. This way the file always gets closed even when you hit a 'return' statement.

Comment: This doesn't yet explain why it would be better than writing `Close`, as it's currently done (think of the `return` statements).

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate your `StreamWriter` in a `using` construct:

```
using(Streamwriter sw = new StreamWriter(...)
{
    ...
}
```

This will close (and write buffers to file) in all cases (Exceptions, returns, etc)

In your code you have a lot of `return` statement which leave the stream open and the already written text in the buffers is never flushed to your file...